# How to reuse assets in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, libgdx

Let's say I have a screen A with `Skin` that was loaded in memory by asset manager:

```
private Skin skin;
...
skin = (Skin)MyGame.ResourceManager.getAsset(AssetEnum.UISkin);
//UISkin("Menu/UISkin.json", Skin.class),
```

I need to load the next screen B that also refers to `AssetEnum.UISkin`. The simple way is

1. dispose screen A
2. unload resources of screen A
3. load resources of screen B
4. initialize screen B

But I want to show some loading wheel on the screen A while resources of screen B are still loading. With this extension steps look like

1. load resources of screen B
2. initialise and set screen B
3. dispose screen A
4. unload resources of screen A

The problem is when I call dispose on third step, `skin.dispose()` removes texture of previous screen that I also need on current. And this situation appears every time when "dispose screen A" is after "load resources of screen B". Does anyone have any suggestions? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate static class that loads your assets and keep it until you don't need it anymore.

Lets call this class AssetLoader.

I assume that you know how java works and how libgdx works.

Within the class, AssetLoader, you create 2 methods

```
Public static void load() {}
```

and

```
Public static void dispose() {}
```

Also declare your skin as a static member

```
Public static Skin skin;
```

Within your load() method do the loading of your skin, and within your dispose() method you write your disposal method.

When your want to want to load your assets, call

```
AssetLoader.load();
```

the methods are all static you don't need to initialize AssetLoader in your entire code. Just call it.

When you want to use the skin (for example, your Screen1() method)

```
UISkin("Menu/UISkin.json", AsssetLoader.Skin.class);
```

Finally when your game ends, you call

```
Assetoader.dispose();
```

You can literally put anything in the AssetLoader that is static. Such as textures and soundtracks. The benefit is that you only need to call the load() method once in your entire code and you can use it for the entire duration of your game. Just remember to dispose it when you don't need it anymore.

EDIT: Another thing you can do is to use AssetManager
More details [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

Comment: This can actually works but I try to separate resources of each screen. If I have static members it really hard to scale this system. Each screen can has, for example, 50 assets and also I don't know order of screen pushes. It can be A->B->C->D оr A->D->A->C and how can I control which asset is need to dispose? With this logic I must set all possibly-reusable objects static.

Comment: The only thing I could think of at the moment is: Create another class. Pass on the required assets from Screen1 to this class. Then tell the Screen 2 to access that class. And finally load the assets of the missing assets.

Comment: omg it seems I don't need to call skin.dispose() because it's inside of asset manager :D Thank you for suggestions!